# How to create forms similar to admin block forms

Tags: 6, forms, blocks

I want to create a form similar to Admin Block Settings form.
So far I have created [draggable table](http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/drupal-drag-and-drop-tables-in-custom-modules), how can I add Enable and Disable sections to the form ?
I checked out Draggable Views module but it does not work out for me as I am creating a custom form.

Comment: Do you mean the tables with the Drag and drop element? Like taxonomy list or menu element list?

Comment: @OskarCalvo I have already done Draggable Tables but what I was looking for is like block page, where you have a enable/disable section.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two examples to learn how to build a custom module with drag and drop elements:

http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/drupal-drag-and-drop-tables-in-custom-modules

http://www.computerminds.co.uk/quick-guide-using-drupal-add-tabledrag-and-enjoying-jquery-drag-and-drop-loveliness

Oskar